# How to draw on a sketchpad on Jupyter Notebook without the cell running forever?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter

I have implemented a code snippet in a Jupyter Notebook cell to create a simple drawing application using Tkinter. The functionality involves allowing the user to draw on a canvas, save the drawn image, and display a download link. While the drawing functionality works as intended, the cell seems to run indefinitely, preventing the execution of subsequent cells.

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageDraw
import PIL
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

width = 200  # canvas width
height = 200 # canvas height
center = height//2
white = (255, 255, 255) # canvas back

from IPython.display import display, HTML

def save():
    # Save image to hard drive
    filename = "user_input.jpg"
    output_image.save(filename)

    # Convert the image to a NumPy array
    img_array = np.array(output_image)
    print("Image as NumPy array shape:", img_array.shape)

    # Display a download link
    display(HTML(f'<a href="{filename}" download="{filename}">Click here to download the image</a>'))

def paint(event):
    x1, y1 = (event.x - 1), (event.y - 1)
    x2, y2 = (event.x + 1), (event.y + 1)
    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black", width=5)
    draw.line([x1, y1, x2, y2], fill="black", width=5)

master = Tk()

# create a tkinter canvas to draw on
canvas = Canvas(master, width=width, height=height, bg='white')
canvas.pack()

# create an empty PIL image and draw object to draw on
output_image = PIL.Image.new("RGB", (width, height), white)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output_image)
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", paint)

# add a button to save the image
button = Button(text="save", command=save)
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm guessing you'd need to stop the cell manually or add a "Quit" button to stop the application as you would for a desktop application